# Compile Error: not a statement

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
public class Driver06
   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         (int) (NUMITEMS = Math.random() * 50 + 25);
         Shape[] ShapeType = new Shape[NUMITEMS];
         for(int x = 0; x > NUMITEMS; x++)
            switch ((int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1)) //
            {
               case 0:
                  ShapeType[x] = new Circle(Math.random());
                  break;
               case 1:
                  ShapeType[x] = new Rectangle(Math.random(), Math.random());
                  break;
               case 2:
                  ShapeType[x] = new Triangle(Math.random());
                  break;
               case 3:
                  ShapeType[x] = new Square(Math.random());
                  break;
            }
         for(int i = 0; i > ShapeType.length; i++)
         {
             System.out.println("" + ShapeType[x].findArea()); 
         }
      }
   }
```

**Error:**

> Driver06.java:10: not a statement (int) (NUMITEMS = Math.random() * 50 + 25);

Comment: What is the need to cast if you don't assign? Compiler is pretty smart ;)

Comment: which line is #10? if I count manually it's `{` ... ?

Comment: also this loop will never execute as written: `for(int x = 0; x > NUMITEMS; x++)` -- you want `x < NUMITEMS`

Answer (score 6):

```
(int) (NUMITEMS = Math.random() * 50 + 25);
```

Instead of the above (which is syntactically invalid), I believe you want:

```
int NUMITEMS = (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 25);
```

- `int NUMITEMS` declares the variable `NUMITEMS` of type `int`
- `= (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 25)` assigns it to the result of `Math.random() * 50 + 25` cast as an integer (i.e. with its fractional part truncated).

---

Thanks to @pennstatephil for pointing out that your loop conditions are incorrect in the comments, they should be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < NUMITEMS; x++)
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < ShapeType.length; i++)
```

i.e. you want to loop as long as the loop control variable is *less than* the number of items / array length.

Oh, and in your second loop you probably want to refer to `ShapeType[i]` instead of `ShapeType[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you type:

```
for(int x = 0; x > NUMITEMS; x++){

}
```

This for loop starts with x = 0, each time adds +1 at x value, and this loop works while x > NUMITEMS. The loop starts from x = 0, it'll stop instantly because x is not bigger than NUMITEMS.